# Three Sensors with 2 rgb leds Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Currently, am using 3 touch capacitive sensors, 2 common anode RGB leds and Arduino. Sen0 will have three conditions:

1. press0 light up all red leds,
2. press1 light up all green leds,
3. press2 light up all blue leds.

Then when Sen0 at press0 if I press Sen1 1 red should light up. when sen0 at press0 if I press sen2 two red leds should light up.

Sen0 at press1 if I press sen1 it should light up 1 green led and if I press sen2 it should light up two green leds.

Sen0 at press2 if I press sen1 it should light up 1 blue led and if I press sen2 it should light up 2 blue leds.

Thank you for your help! I added the sketch for the code as well.

the code:

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjKW7.png
```

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the code formatting. Not sure how you got it this strange - simply copy/paste from your code editor, then press the code formatting icon `{}`. Also, what exactly is the question? What part of the code is not working, what happens and what do you expect?

Comment: Instead of defining constants you have declared so many variables .

Comment: Hi Kiran, would explain to me what do you mean please thank you

Comment: And what's your problem? Do you want someone to write a different sketch for you? BTW: `senState0 = digitalRead(sen0);` you cannot have executable code outside a function.

Comment: thank datafiddler. The problem is If I press sen0 three times which means press2 and green leds on and I press sen1 and sen2 once rend led on which is suppose to be green.

Comment: Perhaps if you indicated what it **is doing** that differs from what you want it to do. In other words, describe the problem that you are experiencing. Also, do you have a circuit diagram? I'm not sure what it is not doing, but it is possible that the problem is in the hookup...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of observations based upon what we know so far.

I believe capacitive touch sensors do not return HIGH / LOW results unless they are a "digital capacatitive touch sensor". Non digital ones will likely return an analog values, so you might need to use an AnalogRead function.

In this case your code might read something like this:

```
  senVal1 = analogRead(sen1);
  if (senVal1 > 800) {
    // Do sensor is touched stuff
  }
```

Also, assuming your LED's are connected to Arduino via their cathodes (i.e. LOW = ON), then you never seem to turn any of the LED's off. That is there is no code like this:

```
  digitalWrite(LEDX, HIGH);
```

So the result is probably that all of the LED's will come on and stay on.

Finally, you might want to introduce some debounce and / or hasn't let go yet. Consider the following:

```
void loop() {
  // read the state of the sensor0 value:
  senState0 = digitalRead(sen0);        // This appears to be in the wrong place!!!!
  // check if the sensortouch is pressed.
  // if it is, the sensorState is HIGH:
  if ( senState0 == HIGH ) {
    if (sentouchCount1 % numberOfLED1 == 0 ){ 
      digitalWrite(LEDR,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1,LOW);
      }
```

The loop function will be called many times per second (e.g. thousands of times per second). Your logic is effectively "Is Sensor0 pressed?". This test is executed many, many times per second. So, your tests involving "sentouchCount1" will be exectued many many times per second.

**Assuming** you actually change the value of sentouchCount1 somewhere by adding one to it, this will quickly cycle through all possible values of the if statements resulting in all of the LED's appearing to instantaneously turn on.

However, you do not change the value of sentouchCount1, so only the first if that turns on LEDR and LEDR1 is probably activated.

Oh, and in relation to the "hasn't let go" bit, consider the following code:

```
boolean isPressed = false;

loop() {
  if (senState0 == HIGH && !isPressed) {
     // do stuff when we detect that the switch is pressed
     isPressed = true;      // Make sure we don't keep doing this for the entire
                            // duration the user is touching the switch!
  } else if (senState0 == LOW && isPressed) {
    isPressed = false;      // User has let go of the button, so enable the
                            // previous if block that takes action when the user
                            // presses the button.
  }        // You might need to search "debouncing a switch", but I do not think this is required for capacative touch sensors (especially digital ones).
```

As per my comment below, you probably need to do something like this:

```
boolean isSensor1Touched = false;

void loop() {
  // read the state of the sensor0 value:
  senState0 = digitalRead(sen0);        // This appears to be in the wrong place!!!!
  // check if the sensortouch is pressed.
  // if it is, the sensorState is HIGH:
  if ( senState0 == HIGH && ! isSensor1Touched) {
    sentouchCount1++;
    isSensor1Touched = true;
    if (sentouchCount1 % numberOfLED1 == 0 ){ 
      digitalWrite(LEDR,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDR1,LOW);
      }
    if (sentouchCount1 % numberOfLED1 == 1 ){ 
      digitalWrite(LEDG,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDG1,LOW);
    }
    if (sentouchCount1 % numberOfLED1 == 2){ 
      digitalWrite(LEDB,LOW);
      digitalWrite(LEDB1,LOW);
    }
  } else if (senState0 == LOW && isSensor1Touched) {
    isSensor1Touched = false;
  }

  // Then repeat for other sensors...
```

Comment: they are a digital capacitive touch sensor and common anode rgb led

Comment: OK, so the bit about analog sensors won't apply, the rest will. Also, this comment still applies: *can you indicate what it is doing that differs from what you want it to do. In other words, describe the problem that you are experiencing.* that will also help. Can you go through my answer and see if I've guessed any of your problems and if so, whether my suggestions help you. If they do, can you accept this answer please.

Comment: Thank you GMc. the problem is, Sen1 and sen2 don't read the state of sen0. this how should it works: if I pressed 3 times for sen0 then 3 green leds will on,  If I press once sen1 it should light up 1 green led and if press once sen2 it should light up two green led.

Comment: I still think the problems are as per my answer 1) You never increment the "sentouchCountX" variables and 2) You do not have any logic that detects the "touch" and the "release". I will update my answer with one possible solution. But your problem is still not very clear.

Comment: well, attached the logic diagram of the code, I think that would give you clear information

Comment: Have you tried any of my suggestions? Do they work for you, if not what is still not working?

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't work for me. thank for your help. the same problem

Comment: Given the code above, which is all anyone has to go on, the behaviour you are trying to achieve is *not possible*. It is not possible because there is no place in the code where you are tracking button presses. So it doesn't matter how many times you touch the sensor, you never change the value of the "sentouchCountX" variables. So you can touch it 3 times or 3 million times, nothing different will happen.

Also I am confused. In your question, you mention 2 RGB LED's. but in your comment, you say "*3* green leds will on".

Comment: Also take ut step by step. Focus on sensor 0. Does it do what you want? For example when first upload your sketch, are leds off? If not set all the pins to HIGH in setup(). That bit is missing in your original post. *Next* when you touch sensor 0 only, do the red leds turn on? *Next* if you touch sensor 0 only, do the green leds turn on? What about the red ones, should they remain on or turn off at this point?

Comment: Well,  mean 2 Green. Well I tried still it hasn't work for me

Comment: Alem, it is difficult to help you if your only reply is "I tried but it still doesn't work". Tried what? (show the code) Did nothing change? Did you answer any of the questions I asked in the previous post? "I tried and it still hasn't worked for me" does not provide any additional information. To debug something you need to take it step by step and focus on the details.

Comment: GMc, I am thankful for your help. I sorted out the problem. Many thanks

Comment: That's great. Can you please post the solution as an answer so that others might benefit?